# Closing custom selectbox when opening a new one

Tags: jquery

I've decided to make a working jsfiddle example for this to make it easy for suggestions.

I have a custom button that toggles down a list.  It basically functions as a `<select>` input but can actually be styled the way I'm needing.  I need to write some extra logic into my jquery that will close any other open select boxes if you go to click a new one.

I have every other scenario of needing to close the select box taken care.  Code is below.

jsFiddle: [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/LAr4E/)

Can anyone modify my js to close anything that is .not() the select box currently being clicked?

Comment: "Can anyone modify my js to close anything that is .not() the select box currently being clicked?"... Is there anything wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using active status classes just target an already active selectbox and close it down, then proceed to do the rest

```
$(this).children('.btn.select').click(function(){

    $('.active').next('.options').slideUp('regular'); // Close the active one

    if ($(this).next('.options').is(':hidden')){
        $(this).next('.options').slideDown('regular');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.options').slideUp('regular');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    return false
});
```

I would also reduce generally the selector mess and the animation duration, just to make the code prettier and cleaner:

```
$(this).children('.btn.select').click(function(){   
    $('.options').slideUp(800); // Close the active one
    $options = $(this).next('.options');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $options.slideDown(800);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $options.slideUp(800);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    return false
});
```

Comment: I'm going to use a slight modification of the first suggestion here.  I also removed the active class and slide the options up before the if/else.

I tried cleaning the selector mess, but for some reason that wasn't working.  Time to leave well enough alone.

Answer (score 0):

`.not()` is your friend.

```
$(this).children('.btn.select').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    var opt = btn.next('.options');

    if (opt.is(':hidden')) 
    {
        opt.slideDown('regular');
        btn.addClass('active');

        $('.options').not(opt).
          slideUp('regular').
          removeClass('active');
    } 
    else 
    {
        opt.slideUp('regular');
        btn.removeClass('active');
    }
    return false
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAr4E/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
$('.options').slideUp('regular');
```

Like:

```
$('.selectbox').each(function(){
    $(this).children('.btn.select').click(function(){
        $('.options').slideUp('regular');
        if ($(this).next('.options').is(':hidden')){
            $(this).next('.options').slideDown('regular');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).next('.options').slideUp('regular');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        return false
    });
});
```